# POSIX multi-value option_argument syntax

Tags: posix

I have read https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html.

I understand that a short `option_argument` can look like `-kvalue` or `-k value`.

If we want to specify multiple values for the `option_argument`, we can write `-kvalue1 -kvalue2`, `-k value1 -k value2`, or a mix of both syntaxes.

My question:

Is `-k value1 value2` valid and equivalent to the above?

Further, what about for long `option_argument`s?
Is `--key value1 value2` the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-k value1 value2` is usually equivalent to `-k value1 -- value2`, where `value1` is the *option_argument* to `-k`, and `value2` is an *operand* (a program argument like in `echo value2` or `ls value2`).  Were you to implement this by manipulating `optind/OPTIND`, you would have the following problems:

- In `-k value1 value2 ... valueN input-file`, how would you know that `input-file` is an input file and not intended as `-k input-file`?
- Does `-k -z` mean `-k` had 0 arguments, followed by the `-z` option, or is `-z` treated as an *option_argument*?  What about `-k value1 value2 -z value4`?

Also, `-k value1 -k value2` would typically replace `value1` with `value2`, so it would be a good idea to document the additive behavior of `-k` if it were implemented.  You should avoid `-(` and `-)` options.  On Solaris, per its [CLIP guidelines](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26505_01/html/816-5165/intro-1.html) (scroll down to the *Command Syntax Standard: Guidelines* section), the `(` and `)` characters delimit long option names, like `?(help)V(version)` would recognize `--help` as `-?` and `--version` as `-V`.

As for long option arguments, POSIX does not support them, whether that is `-old-style arg`, `--gnu-style=arg`, or `--gnu-style arg`.  An optstring `"-:k:"` is not portable according to POSIX either because `-` is not alphanumeric; even if it is supported, you would also need to deal with changing `optind/OPTIND` in the case of `--key value1` to set the key value to `value1` since `key` is the *option_argument* for the `-` option.

If you are merely writing a utility rather than implementing `getopt` rules in your own option parser, an alternative would be to rely on `getopt_long`, keeping the [implementation differences](https://man.openbsd.org/getopt_long#IMPLEMENTATION_DIFFERENCES) in mind; it is widely available, even if it is not specified by POSIX. You could also use a separate option parsing library (or shell function or whatever you would use in the language you're dealing with).